# how to specify the URL for calling the webservice from android emulator?

Tags: android, .net, web-services

I want to use my local .net webservice (which is not yet hosted) in an android application in my local machine.Is it possible? What URL should I use to call the web service ?

MY static IP address is 192.168.0.163 and port number is 1736 for my IIS server.Please Help..

Answer (score 1):

in android emulator, open a browser and navigate to your internal network ip, or make a ping request from emulator terminal.

if test succeeds, you can specify your local ip and port as service host.

Comment: I did not get you exactly.